# How to mock methods from an imported class from a package in Javascript and Jest?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to mock the returned values from methods from a class from a package. This package holds my API code and the methods call my API.

Now I have mocked the module, but then the mock only returns undefined since there's no implementation mocked.

This is how I am mocking at the moment:

```
import { Api } from 'restClient';

jest.mock('restClient', () => jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
  Api: jest.fn(),
})));

describe('Upon instantiating', () => {
const api = new Api();

  jest.spyOn(api.prototype, 'getUsers').mockResolvedValue(getUsersSuccess);

})
```

Now when I run this I am getting the message that TypeError: _restClient.Api is not a constructor.

Does anyone know how to do this properly?

Comment: If you expect restClient to have Api export, you shouldn't wrap it with jest.fn().mockImplementation